# Modify multiple rows in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

assume I have a dataframe. I would like to modify a list of rows with certain value.

For example, below is my dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"strings":["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], 
  "value":["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"], 
  "price":["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]})
```

And I want to replace all cells with '0' in row C, D, and E, which is like below. Rows = ['C', 'D', 'E']

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"strings":["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], 
  "value":["a", "b", "0", "0", "0"], 
  "price":["1", "2", "0", "0", "0"]})
```

I know we can achieve this by simply giving the rows' name and certain value, but as we have lots of rows to be modified, how could we do this more efficiently using pandas?

Anyone hint please?

Comment: Do you mean COLUMN C, D, E? C, D and E are not rows

Comment: @dahui C, D, E are not Columns either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want all the values in columns "price" and "value" to be set to zero for rows where column "strings" has values either C, D or E.

```
df.loc[df.strings.isin(["C", "D", "E"]), df.columns.difference(["strings"])] = 0
df
Out[82]: 
  price strings value
0     1       A     a
1     2       B     b
2     0       C     0
3     0       D     0
4     0       E     0
```

Comment: `difference` is better :)

Comment: Thanks, but if I have hundreds of rows required to be modified, what should I do??

Comment: @Sakura How do you identify the rows that should be modified? Are they in a list or something like that? Do they follow a rule?

Comment: That is a list of them, no particular rule.

Comment: @Sakura then you can just pass the name of the list. For example `df.loc[df.strings.isin(name_of_the_list), df.columns.difference(["strings"])] = 0`

Comment: What if I want to update only one coumn ? In the above case only price

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way of doing it,

Consider your data is like this:

```
  price strings value
0     1       A     a
1     2       B     b
2     3       C     c
3     4       D     d
4     5       E     f
```

Now lets make `strings` column as the index:

```
df.set_index('strings', inplace=True)

#Result
        price value
strings
A           1     a
B           2     b
C           3     c
D           4     d
E           5     f
```

Now set the values of rows `C, D, E` as `0`

```
df.loc[['C', 'D','E']] = 0

#Result
        price value
strings
A           1     a
B           2     b
C           0     0
D           0     0
E           0     0
```